# SIM card for weekend stay in Italy, mostly for internet access

Tags: cellphones, italy, venice

I will travel to Italy in one month (to Venice) and I would like to buy a SIM card so that I can access internet during my weekend stay. What options are available and which ones do you recommend? I have an iPhone 5S and my home operator is Vodafone.